# Найти сумму всех элементов массива в java, которые без остатка делятся на 3

Tags: java

Всем привет!

**Суть задачи:**

Нужно реализовать публичный статический метод **calculateSum()**, который принимает в качестве аргумента массив целых чисел. Метод высчитывает и возвращает сумму всех элементов массива, **которые делятся без остатка на 3 (три)**. **В случае пустого массива метод должен вернуть 0.**

**Как должна работать программа:**

```
int[] numbers = {8, 9, 21, 19, 18, 22, 7};

App.calculateSum(numbers); // 48
```

**Мое решение**

```
public class App {
 
    public static Integer calculateSum(int[] numbers){

        if(numbers.length ==0){
            return null;
        }

        int sum=numbers[0];
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            int currentElement= numbers[i];
            if(currentElement%3==0){
               sum= currentElement;
            }
            
        }
        return sum;
     }
  }
```

Пмомогите мне пожалуйста найти ошибку.

Comment: Ты не указал в чём ошибка заключается

Comment: expected: 48
│               but was: 18
Проблемы с делением на 3

Comment: 1. При пустом массиве возвращается null, а должен 0; 2. Начальное значение sum numbers[0], а должно быть 0; 3. В sum присваивается currentElement, а должен прибавляться

Comment: Прогонял в Online Ide https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler-ide/
На выводе получил вот такое:[I@1c655221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if(numbers.length ==0){
>     return null;
> }
> ```

Выкинуть.

> ```
> int sum=numbers[0];
> ```

```
int sum = 0;
```

> ```
> sum= currentElement;
> ```

```
sum += currentElement;
```

Comment: Так и сделал,но все равно не хочет нормально складывать:

Comment: На выходе вместо 48 пишет 7

Comment: @PeteAlexandrovich, неправда.

Comment: ты прав,  я внимательно посмотрел и перекопилил- тут за нейтральные элементы надо брать примитивы в виде 0 , а не null!

Comment: , благодарю за объяснение!

Comment: @Regent, благодарю!

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо за совет!